# Origin of Java.awt.component for MouseEvent.getX()

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am trying to calculate the distance I move a mouse within a box, I am using the MouseEvent.getX() and MouseEvent.getY() to calculate the start position of the mouse and then I have another method saving the position and calculating the distance the mouse has moved. Here is some code I wrote to demonstrate this.

```
BlankArea.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(){
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mm){
                System.out.println("Position (" + mm.getX() + ", " 
                                                + mm.getY() + ")");
                savePosition(mm.getX(), mm.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent md) {
                System.out.println("Position (" + mm.getX() + ", " 
                                                + mm.getY() + ")");
                savePosition(mm.getX(), mm.getY());
            }
        });
```

My Question is: The Java API states that getX() & getY() returns the horizontal & vertical coordinate relative to the source component respectively. What is the source component? What unit is the output coordinate measured in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) What is the source component?

Like Mr.777 said, it is the component that you added the listener to, so in your example it is `BlankArea`.

2) What unit are the output coordinates measured in?

Like Mr.777 said, they are measured in pixels with the origin (0, 0) being at the top-left of the component.

I would recommend reading some of the Java tutorials online.  Here is a good page to look at the Java coordinate system [Coordinates (Java Tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html).

Answer (score 4):

welcome to Stack Overflow...
The source component is actually the component you have written listener for and the output coordinate is measured in pixels...

I hope this helps... If you still have questions, please ask them...

Comment: Thanks Mr.777 Where would (0,0) be within the source component do you know?